# Which services do I need to run Java EE application on Windows Azure?

Tags: windows, azure, web

I was hoping to run a JSP & Servlet website on Windows Azure. What services basically do I need to purchase to run that on the website.
Basic need of website:

1. SQL database
2. JAVA support & Tomcat server
3. Bandwidth
4. Web storage

But I'm a little bit lost here : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?

Answer (score 1):

**Java Support and Tomcat**
 Azure Virtual Machine. You can choose between a Windows Virutal Machine or a Linux Virutal Machine.

**SQL Database**

1. Depending on your needs you could either install SQL Server or MySQL (since you said SQL database) on the Virtual Machine machine.
2. You could choose a separate DB server SQL Server Virtual Machine.
3. The third option for SQL Database would be to go with **SQL Azure** which has high availability built in. Each has its pros and cons and I'd recommend doing a detailed study before choosing either one. I'd personally recommend looking at SQL Azure.

**Storage**
In terms of Web Storage you would need to get a storage account. Look at the Locally Redundant Storage or Geo-Redundant Storage options.

Hope this helps